# How to render an animation of one render layer?

Tags: render-passes

Right now if i press the render button under render layer (inside the compositor) it will render only one single frame.

Comment: the renderer will use your compositing as long as the option to use it is checked (which is by default), this whether you use video or frame rendering; so you can just click on the button to render animation in the render tab.

Comment: Thanks! It was kinda hard to find it.